# NPM does not flatten global dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

When I run `npm install` locally in the project dir, the deps are flattened correctly. When I run `npm install -g` to install some modules globally, they are not flattened. How do I flatten them?

Probably helpful info:

```
[user@server ~]$ nvm ls
->     v11.11.0
default -> node (-> v11.11.0)
node -> stable (-> v11.11.0) (default)
stable -> 11.11 (-> v11.11.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.15.1 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.15.3 (-> N/A)

[user@server ~]$ node -v
v11.11.0

[user@server ~]$ npm -v
6.7.0

[user@server ~]$ npm root -g
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.11.0/lib/node_modules
```

The server is running on Centos 7.

And the modules I'm talking about are for example `webpack` (and other `webpack-*` modules), `babel-core` (and other `babel-*` modules), `vue`. So it does not looks like it's caused by the modules but rather by npm itself.

Comment: Did you try `npm -g dedupe` ?

Comment: Yes, it just prints something similar to `up to date in 0.05s` but the dependencies are still nested